# Dax - Distinctcount only when two conditions are met

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a measure to distinctcount number of chats assisted by a human. In order to calculate this measure two conditions must be met: Same Session ID number must both have "Nei" and "Ja" in column 'Assistert av Menneske'

[image]

When both of those two criteria are met it means that the chatbot has connected the customer with a human.

Also I want to know which customers are using human chat, the key column here is "Firmakode" (connected to a dimension table), as you can see it turns blank when "Assistert av menneske" cointans "Ja".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (replace 'Message' with your table name):

```
Human Chat Count = 
  var sessionsJa = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Message'[session_id]), 'Message'[Assistert av Menneske] = "Ja")
  var sessionsNei = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Message'[session_id]), 'Message'[Assistert av Menneske] = "Nei")
  var result = COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(sessionsJa, sessionsNei))
  RETURN result
```

Regarding your second part - maybe create a Calculate Column similar to:

```
Firmakode v2 = 
  var curSession = [session_id]
  var result = IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK([Firmakode])) && [Firmakode] <> "",
    [Firmakode],
    CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK('Message'[Firmakode], 1), FILTER(ALL('Message'), 'Message'[session_id] = curSession && 'Message'[Firmakode] <> ""))
  )
  RETURN result
```

And use this for your relationship.

You can also do something similar in PowerQuery if you prefer.

Comment: I was hoping this would explain which customers are using Human chat, but it doesn't. I will clarify a bit more in the question above.

Comment: Updated answer to include Calculated Column with `Firmakode` for that session id.

Comment: That worked, thank you